# Read numbers in the name of a file by NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have to extract a file to an output folder in my NSIS installer. The name of the file contains its version number. I need a method to read the number written in the name of my file.

**Example File name:**

```
MyFile_4.3_runtime_80968_x64.exe
```

I used the following code to read it automatically:

```
Var Version
Section
    ${GetFileVersion} "F:\FilesToBeInstalled\MyFile_4.3_runtime_?????_x64.exe" $Version
    MessageBox MB_OK "Version: $Version"
SectionEnd
```

earlier it used to work for me. But suddenly it has stopped working. If I write the proper number instead of writing `?????` then it works. For example, the following code works for me:

```
Var Version
Section
    ${GetFileVersion} "F:\FilesToBeInstalled\MyFile_4.3_runtime_80698_x64.exe" $Version
    MessageBox MB_OK "Version: $Version"
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

[`GetFileVersion`](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Includes/FileFunc/GetFileVersion.md) reads the [version-information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003(v=vs.85).aspx) of the file, it does not parse the file-name. It has likely been a coincidence that it worked before.

You can use [`WordFind2x`](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Includes/WordFunc/WordFind2X.md) to search between two delimiters:

```
!include "WordFunc.nsh"

Var Version
Var File

Section

    # find instances of MyFile_4.3_runtime*
    FindFirst $0 $File "F:\FilesToBeInstalled\MyFile_4.3_runtime*.exe"
    loop:
      StrCmp $File "" done

      # parse hit for version string
      ${WordFind2X} $File "MyFile_4.3_runtime_" ".exe" "-1" $Version
      DetailPrint "$File contains version $Version"

      FindNext $0 $File
      Goto loop
    done:
    FindClose $0

SectionEnd
```

Comment: The line ` ${WordFind2X} "MyFile_4.3_runtime_80968.exe" "MyFile_4.3_runtime_" ".exe" "-1" $Version` uses `MyFile_4.3_runtime_80968.exe` ad that is my problem that I do not know beforehand that `80968` is present in the name of the file.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added FindFirst to find all instances of that name pattern. If can rule out multiple files following the naming pattern, you can break the loop after the first hit.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the `_x64` is also present in the name of the file just before `.exe`. Now that will create problem. How can I deal with this situation?

Comment: Just add it to the second delimiter, e.g. `"_x64.exe"`